# HTML/CSS issue Firefox vs. Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have small problem with a picture frame and I only know the basics of HTML/CSS. In Chrome it is appearing higher than the original in Firefox.

Situation with Firefox (original):

[image]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://www.shrani.si/f/31/iN/4yZwUGma/1/infirefoxmozzila.jpg))</sub>

Situation with Chrome:

[image]

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to provide some code to illustrate the problem. http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see a brief snippet of code concerning this part, in order to solve your problem.

However, it seems to be an inconsistence caused by the different magnitudes set by default on each browser. Look forward for some CSS reset stylesheets. If you're using HTML5, I recommend you taking a look at [html5boilerplate](http://www.html5boilerplate.com), or if you'd only like to fix your small problem, go for [html5reset.css](http://code.google.com/p/html5resetcss/downloads/list). If not, a search on the net for `css reset` will do.